# Subdomain only work when I add the port number using Nginx and wildcard

Tags: node.js, nginx, server, wildcard, wildcard-subdomain

I am creating a web server using nginx, I did managed to get everything working but my server got wiped out so I need to redo all over again and now I am facing a problem I did not have.

I use Nodejs and express

I did install wildcard.

When I navigate to the home page, all good, it is working, however when I go to a any other pagr, I have to add :3000 for it to work or else I am taken to the main page (if I try a subdomain) and get a 404 if I got to let say "example.com/page1".

Let us say my domain is example.com

to go to dom.example.com, I need to type in dom.example.com:3000 or else I will be taken to example.com

here is my config file :

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com example.com *.example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
    }
}
```

and my node server :

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
var sub = require('wildcard-subdomains')

app.use(sub({
    namespace: 's',
    whitelist: ['www', 'app'],
}))
.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send("Hello World!");
})
.get('/s/:p/', (req, res) => {
    res.send(`sub domain`)
    console.log('ooo')
})

const port = 3000;
const server = app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

Comment: maybe it's the application that redirects it. Have you tried setting headers for the proxy pass?

Comment: I did a server reset, started fresh, but you hit a point, if I remove the :3000 on the subdomain, it goes directly to https

Comment: then you need a 443 block with certificate

Comment: I did add     add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=0;  Now it does not redirect but it goes directly to the main page if I do not add the :3000

Comment: The problem is more complicate than I though, I am editing the question